# How to make legend element order along data frame rows but not reorder?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to fill the each bar color from left to right along a defined color vector. But the legend will reorder the color. How to display the legend element as the order in data frame rows? I give a example as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:4,b=2:5,c=c('b','d','a','e'),d=factor(1:4))
col <- c('#a6cee3', '#1f78b4','#6a3d9a', '#b2df8a')
```

the bar color order I wanted

```
ggplot(df)+
  geom_col(aes(x=a,y=b,fill=d))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=col)
```

If use columns `c` to fill color , the legend will reorder as 'a','b','c','d'. It looks like colors parameter passing to legend ,then filling bars refer to legend. So the bars colors are disorder. How to avoid legend element reorder? Can it show as 'd' 'c' 'b' 'a'? 
If not ,can bar colors order consisit with `col`?

```
ggplot(df)+
  geom_col(aes(x=a,y=b,fill=c))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=col)
```

Comment: Try `df$c <- factor(df$c, levels = df$c)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `forcats::fct_inorder()` to turn `c` into a factor with its levels in the current order:

```
ggplot(df)+
    geom_col(aes(x=a,y=b,fill=forcats::fct_inorder(c)))+
    scale_fill_manual(values=col)
```

Answer (score 1):

The usual order of `factor` column is alphabetic.  If we need to do any change in that behavior, call the `factor` with the `levels` specified in the custom order we needed

```
df$c <- factor(df$c, levels = unique(df$c))
```

Upon running the OP's `ggplot` code, it would give the output as below

[image]